# What's the "time to hire" in user activity on Upwork?

Tags: upwork

What's the "time to hire" in [user activity on  Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/nx/reports/client/user-activity)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Upwork tech support defined the "time to hire" in [user activity on  Upwork](https://www.upwork.com/nx/reports/client/user-activity) as follows:

> The time between posting the job and extending the last offer and closing the job post.

To my surprise, it is not some averaged time.